# How to display a Chinese map in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, fluttermap

I need to show the location of a residential area in China in a Flutter Web app as a `Widget`. **OpenStreetMap** and other Western map providers like **Google** and **Bing** are insufficient because they do not offer highly detailed data at this level and often show outdated information.

I tried using the package [`flutter_map`](https://docs.fleaflet.dev/), however, by default it uses the API of **OpenStreetMap**, which is not enough for my situation. I need to use a Chinese provider like **Baidu**, but I am not used to them especially since I am not Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the low number of quality Flutter packages available to display maps, Chinese map providers are generally hard to use for non-Chinese citizens or for apps that should work outside China.

For **Baidu**, [there is a package for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_baidu_mapapi_map), but it has no English documentation at all, and it is available only for Mobile apps, not for the Web. Furthermore, using it requires an API key from the [*Baidu Map Developer Platform*](https://lbsyun.baidu.com/), which in turn requires an identity verification using an ID card, meaning that it is impossible to be used by a non-Chinese citizen.

Another provider is **Amap** (高德地图), which is one of the **Alibaba** products. It also requires a verified account but it can be done quickly through **Alipay**. They have an easy-to-use [static maps API](https://lbs.amap.com/api/webservice/guide/api/staticmaps/), but I found out that it rejects any connection attempt from non-Chinese IPs!

However, the website [Amap.com](https://amap.com) works correctly from outside China. Therefore, we can use the same API that the website is built on. Using the *Network* tab of the *Developer tools* in the browser and filtering by images, we can see the following requests:

[image: Tiles requests]

These are API calls that return the map tiles corresponding to the displayed region. From their URLs, they appear to follow the *[Slippy Map Tile Names](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)* similarly to **OpenStreetMap**.

This is the default standard used in `flutter_map`. Consequently, we can use one of these URLs while replacing the `x`, `y`, `z` variables:

```dart
    FlutterMap(
        options: const MapOptions(),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
            urlTemplate: 'https://webrd03.is.autonavi.com/appmaptile?lang=zh_cn&size=1&scale=1&style=8&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
            tileProvider: CancellableNetworkTileProvider(),
          ),
        ],
    );
```

There is a parameter `lang=zh_cn` that can be changed to `lang=en` to display the labels in English instead of Chinese, but it is not recommended to do so because the English version is missing a lot of details compared to the Chinese version. Other parameters should not be changed.